# How to open app based on last viewController used in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I currently have a quiz game app where each round is represented by a different view controller.  When the user closes the app and later re-opens the app I want it to keep the same score and stay on the same viewcontroller it was last on. I believe NSUserDefaults is the way to go but not sure how to set it up to remember the last round it was on.  Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an user defaults object using:

```
// Create an object reference to the NSUserDefaults class
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

you can request and set objects for this NSUserDefaults class which will be persistent upon closing and opening the app.

```
// Set a string for a key
defaults.setObject("a string", forKey: "myVar")

// Request the object associated with the key:
let myVar : String = defaults.stringForKey("myVar")
```

You can save and update the value for the object whenever you feel like saving it. If you save the StoryBoard ID of the View Controller you want to present when starting the app then you can reopen it whenever the app appears using:

```
// Create a reference to the Storyboard file
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

// Create a reference to the ViewController you want to open
let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID FROM NSUserDefaults")

// Present the ViewController
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: This is good but where would I put the part when it presents the saved viewcontroller, in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: @SwiftyJD in your `AppDelegate`